# Overriding Interrupt & isInterrupted Method in Thread Class

Tags: java, multithreading

In our application we have threads doing a specific action. 
On receive of an event, we need to interrupt those threads in progress.
These threads would check their interrupt status by calling "Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()", 
if it is interrupted, then the thread stops by returining from run method.

Problem we are seeing now is these threads can wait() on a object. 
If the thread is interrupted while wait() on an object, 
the Threads interrupt status is reset and InterruptedException is thrown.

Since 
    1) we have many places where the thread can wait on an object
    2) the methods of other objects which the thread access can wait on an object

we have decided to override the interrupt() & isInterrupted() method. 
The code would look something like

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private boolean isInterrupted = false;

    @Override 
    public void interrupt() {
        isInterrupted = true;
        super.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInterrupted() {
        return isInterrupted;
    }

    public void run() {
        .........
        .........

        try {
            object1.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            /* if interrput() is not overrided, the interrupted flag 
            would be reset */
        }

        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            /* if interrupt is not overrided, isInterrupted would return
            false and the thread would continue to run. */
            return;
        }

        object2.method1(); // method1() can also wait on another object
        /* In method1() also we would need to check isInterrupted and get out
        quickly as soon as possible. This method1() will also be used by
        other threads which will not be interrupted. */

        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            return;
        }
        .........
        .........
    }
}
```

So my questions are

1) Is overriding interrupt() and isInterrupted() as above is a good practice to code?

2) While overriding interrupt() should we maintain the same behavior i.e. throw 
   interrupted and other exceptions as stated in the java doc of interrupt() method
   in Thread class? Actually we need the threads that are waiting to be interrupted
   but the interrupted flag to be set.

3) What about Thread.interrupted() method which is static. 
    With the above overriding we shouldn't use this method right?

Comment: Arun. could you please explain little bit more about your second concern . I don't see the reason for overriding interrupt() yet. What is your expectation when the thread waits on Object so long? how do you terminate if your override interrupt?

Comment: And you havent showed how you terminate thread based on Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() method.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, overriding these methods is a very bad idea.

Second, I don’t get why you are making your life that hard:

```
try {
  doSomethingThatCanBlock();// e.g. wait()
}
catch(InterruptedException ex) {
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interrupt state
}
```

Now, the next time you check the interrupted state of your `Thread` it will tell you the appropriate state. That’s it.

Comment: +1 Exactly. If the interrupted status gets reset due to an `InterruptedException` being thrown, just set it again by calling `interrupt()`.

Comment: Exactly that was the approach I have used early.It was working.But I encountered a case where my thread called a method on Instance of class from 3rd party jar & the method was waiting on a object.On Interrupt it caught the Interrupted exception and the flag is reset.My thread is unaware of interruption & continues.Problem here is since the thread may call many methods on different objects which in turn can call methods on other objects who may wait on a object & catch the exception.So I need to update too many files in my jar.Also I need to update my dependent jars & third-party-jars.

Comment: Still, hacking the way `Thread` works is a kludge. In general, if any method is catching `InterruptedException` without handling it by itself, it *should* restore the interrupted state like shown in my answer. Everything else may considered a bug. As you have noticed, `Thread.interrupted()` is `static` so overriding does not work anyway. And without declaring your custom flag `volatile` it won’t be thread-safe…

Answer (score 0):

> If the thread is interrupted while wait() on an object, the Threads interrupt status is reset and InterruptedException is thrown.

IMHO this sentence shows that you don't want any interrupt at all. Interrupt can be used to abort thread's execution and you don't seem to want it. Pass some messages instead... if you want to have it flexible, try an [EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). It allows you to send messages to program parts the sender knows nothing about.

Maybe watching some global variables<sup>1</sup> is what you need. Note that using `Thread.interrupt` is dealing with global variables too (and gets rather unusable in face of a `ThreadPool`).

<sup>1 Packed into a singleton or alike.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments , you are forced to override the methods due to third party jar's is not setting Interrupted status Again.

In General  as @Holger mentioned , The method catching `InterruptedException` should restore the state.

if the third party jar's is not setting status back why don't you reset the flag after third party method call ?

```
thirdPartyInstance.method1();   
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    Thread.interrupted();
}
```

So that you can use your Jobs as `Runnable` instead of Actual `Thread` ( You don't need to override the methods) and you can use the way `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to stop your thread.

Finally- if you plan to continue by extend Thread and overriding those methods,

1. Make your status boolean flag as volatile
2. Modify your `isInterrupted()` method as

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean isInterrupted() {
       return isInterrupted || super.isInterrupted();
   }
   ```

To cover if the thread status cleared by `Thread.interrupted();` some where.

Comment: It is wrong to use "Thread.interrupted()" in such way; please, don't confuse interrupted() & interrupt() - they do totally different things